# Compile python3.4 code on Mint 17 to exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation

Is there any way to compile python 3.4 code to exe? I'm using Linux Mint 17. It's little game in pygame. I tried to *python3 setup.py build* | *python setup.py build --plat-name=win-amd64* ( dont compile ) | *python3 setup.py bdist --format=zip* but when I tried open game on windows I have error.

my setup.py:

> import sys
>   from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
>
> buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [])
>
> base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None
>   executables = [
>      Executable('main.py', targetName="Main.exe")
>   ]
>
> setup(
>      name='TheGame',
>      version='',
>      packages=[''],
>      url='',
>      license='',
>      author='',
>      author_email='',
>      description='',
>      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
>      executables = executables
>   )

Comment: Have you checked out PyInstaller? https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki

Comment: Yes, I tried (`pyinstaller main.py`) but I get an error:
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hooks'`

I've search at google but I don't find anything which could helps me

Comment: Can you post your code that you tried the pyinstaller with?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VJnzj60K I paste it on pastebin

Comment: Could you include the Cx_freeze error message?